# How to convert Image string data into a blob

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, download, blob

I am trying to download an image from my server and display it on the client.
I can download the image fine, (DevTools > Network > name-of-request > Preview) displays the image correctly.

I can't get the image to display, and it doesn't save the image within (DevTools > Sources > Page > Top > Localhost).

```
public async getMedia(id: number | undefined): Promise<Blob | undefined> {
    if(!id || id === 0) { return undefined }
    const response = await this.httpClient.get<any>(
        `/api/advertisements/image/${id}`
    );

    const contentType: string = response.headers['content-type'] || 'image/pjpeg';
    const data: string = response.data
    console.log(data)
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType })
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    console.log(url)
    return blob
}
```

**Console Output:**

"����

$.' ",#(7),01444'9=82..."

"blob:http://localhost:57087/a0ae04cd-c0a0-4263-a7fb-dab400a802a4"

[image]

**Additional Information**
This is what I have on the server.

```
[Route("image/{id}")] 
[HttpGet] 
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ImageGet(int id) { 
    
    ....insert download from storage account

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(url);
    await blockBlob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(buffer, 0);
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer, 0, (int)blockBlob.Properties.Length);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
    
    return ResponseMessage(response);

}
```

*To test if this was working at all,*
I uploaded an image from the client using the <input> tab, and then used `window.URL.createObjectURL(File)`, and it created the ObjectURL and displayed correctly.

Comment: If you have the correct image in the response of your networking tab in the devtools, then I don't think you need to do anything with it. You should be able to set this response as the src attribute of an image tag.

Comment: @fonzane
Wouldn't setting 'src=response.data' set it to a very long incoherent string? That would work?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the response type was in the wrong location.

`/api/advertisements/image/${id}`, {} , { responseType: 'blob' }